# Properly Using Generated Texture Mapping for Walls

Tags: texturing

Sorry for stupid question, I knew the solution to this once, but either something got updated since the last time I used this, or I've simply forgotten it...

I'm trying to apply a seamless wall texture for the bedrooms using generated texture mapping along with the repeat turned on.

My problem is that walls that follow the Y axis have really stretched textures, and the walls along the X axis are stretched along the Z axis. So neither direction of my walls display the texture correctly.

Example of what I'm struggling with:
[image]

This will later be used in a game I'm working on, so I'm trying to pack objects together (instead of "Walls Bedroom_1", "Walls Bedroom_2" and so on, I simply have "Walls Bedroom" to make later edits easier and to prevent having too many separate objects.

[image]
(Bedrooms are the rooms with the blue walls)

As far as I've understood it, I've got the settings correct:
[image]

(**Note** I've tried messing around with pretty much every setting shown above. I've even tried to use UV maps, although I don't really want to, but the UVs are all stretched out, even though I've unwrapped using "Follow Active Quads")

[image]

And yes, all faces are quads, I haven't triangulated anything yet.

What am I doing wrong here? This has probably been asked before, but I couldn't find any solutions that worked for me, and manually UV mapping all the walls is too much of a bother this early in the makings, where I mainly want to implement features and add new objects to the level(s)... There has to be an easier solution to this than to manually UV map the entire thing... (Not that I don't like UVs, I usually prefer them, but I think that for walls, there should be an easier approach as it's simple connected faces following two axis (X & Y).

Stripped down version (containing only the walls, material and texture) available below.

[image]

Comment: Anyone struggling with mapping coordinates should watch Bartek Skorupa's video [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0)

Comment: Has the object an "appropriate" bounding box size? The parameters are fine, and the workflow too. Did you try to assing the material to a default cube? Does it work there? Could you provide a sample of your scene?

Comment: My bounding box is probably the cause, but I'm not sure how to change that. And yes, I tried applying the material (with the texture) to the default cube, but the results are actually the same as on the walls (One side with correct horizontal texture, but vertical is messed up, and the side next to it is all stretched and distorted)

Comment: Don't use *Generated* texture coordinates, use *Object* texture coordinates instead

Comment: Tried that as well, but nothing changes when I use it